# external drive access denied

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, permissions

So I tried to google this, change permissions and everything to this drive. It was working fine yesterday and now its not working at all. No idea what to do, but I'm sure you guys can help me! Check this out. I added permissions to all and it still denies me access. So I went to security of the drive to take ownership of drive, but access is still denied EVEN AS ADMIN!? I tried on my other laptop and still access denied. I have no idea what to do. Any more ideas?[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wow I feel dumb. There is a change button at on that last picture. I clicked on that, and had to select everyone and then change permission settings, took like 5 minutes to go through all files and change security settings. SORRY FOR THE STUPIDITY. Live and learn I guess. Thanks anyways.

Comment: But why would it all of a sudden work one day, and the next day not work? Anyone know?